# Having trouble converting /Date(####)/ to MM/dd/yyyy local with MomentJS

Tags: javascript, momentjs, unix-timestamp, epoch

Using external API that's sending me dates such as:

```
/Date(1439596800)/
```

The above date is:

```
August 30, 2015
```

Using momentjs like this:

```
moment("/Date(1439596800)/").format("MM/DD/YYYY");
```

Gets me this:

```
01/17/1970
```

I'm aware that I'm supposed to multiply * 1000 but was hoping there was a specific MomentJS method.

Comment: Which API? You should check the docs and see which date format is returned.

Comment: Stripe. It's a unix timestamp. Might just resort to converting it from the server end.

Comment: Note - the external API is sending bad results.  In that format, the number is *always* supposed to be in terms of milliseconds - not whole seconds.  You should contact that API author rather than trying to work around their error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's rather simple.

Your API gives a UNIX timestamp - by default, `moment(arg)` assumes arg is passed as milliseconds since the 1st January 1970.

For converting it, you must first remove the `/Date(` and `)\`.
I'd use a RegEx that strips all non-digit characters:

```
myString = myString.replace(/\D/g,'');
```

This will leave just the numbers.
Now, you can run

```
moment.unix(myString).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
```

[Moment.js Reference for UNIX timestamps](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp/)

Comment: +1.  This is good.  Another way would be `moment("/Date(1439596800)/","/[Date](X)/")`.  Though really, the source API should be corrected to be in terms of milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

The timestamp is in seconds rather than seconds and [moment()](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-offset/) only understands milliseconds. You can use the [moment.unix()](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp/) function

```
moment.unix("1439596800").format("MM/DD/YYYY"); // returns 08/15/2015
```

However you'll still need to extract `1439596800` from `/Date(1439596800)/`, this can be done with a simple regex

```
moment.unix(/Date\((\d+)\)/.exec(input)[1]).format("MM/DD/YYYY"); 
// returns 08/15/2015
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the extra chacacters. get rid of them first and multiply.

i'm using a regex to get just the digits from inside the parentheses, being sure to escape the slashes and parens.

```
var input = "/Date(1439596800)/"
var regex = /\/Date\((\d+)\)\//;
var match = input.match(regex);
if(match){
  var stringUnixTs = match[1];
  var tsMs = Number(stringUnixTs) * 1000;
  var date = new Date(tsMs); // or pass ts directly into moment
} else { }
```